# My email doesn't show me new invitation?

Tags: chat, contacts, hotmail, windows-live-messenger

I have hotmail account that I used since a long time, recently I noticed that when any one try to add me in MSN Messenger I can't see his invitation. I have to add him my self to start talk with! Any idea to deal with this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check your privacy settings in Messenger and then you should contact MSN support.